# how to move of rewards points above store credit on checkout page

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout

I want to move the 'Apply Rewards' section to be on the 'left side' positioned right above 'Apply Store Credit' drop down. Please help me.[image]

Comment: Magento commerce edition?

Comment: @sohelRana yes magento 2.3